# tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method not getting called

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:   NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("WTF is this getting hit...")

    let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    Cell.textLabel?.text = self.funlists[indexPath.row]

    print("This better be getting hit")


    return Cell;
}
```

for some reason this method isn't getting called.

i have set the following

```
    uiTableView.delegate=self
    uiTableView.dataSource=self
    uiTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

and I have also included,

```
class viewUniversityList: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView cellforrowatindexpath not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939032/uitableview-cellforrowatindexpath-not-called)

Comment: Did you set the tableView delegate and datasource? If you created table view on storyboard then you can add delegate there. if you have set the delegate and datasource then try to add a break point on tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath to check them

Comment: How many rows does the table have? Did you set the table view's `dataSource` and `delegate`?

Comment: @regient i did set the two. when you say go to storyboard and add a delegate, should i just click on the tableView and add a delegate? I tried that but no change

Comment: @rmaddy, for numberOfSectionsInTableView i return 1, and                          func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return  self.funlists.count;
        //return 1
    }, method still isn't getting hit. I did set the tableview's dataSource and delegate!

Answer (score 2):

There might be several reason for this. Some of them are :

- If you are using tableView in your ViewController file, then you should add the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDelegate` delegates, like this :

  ```
  class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate { ... }
  ```
- If you have created a `tableView` in code then you should do the
  following :

  ```
  tableView.delegate = self
  tableView.dataSource = self
  tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
  ```
- If that's all done, or you have create `UITableView` through storyboard with a separate class which is a subClass of `UITableView`, then you **definitely** need to define the
  following methods :

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {...}
  ```

~    `func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {...}` is optional as suggested by @rmaddy, but it's a good practice to define it.

Comment: `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is actually optional. It defaults to `1` section if not implemented.

Comment: Oh okay, I always implemented it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @DhruvRamani thanks for the in depth response! I've edited my question above to show what has already been included and they seem to directly match up with your recommendations. But this method is still not being called unfortunately

Comment: Where have you set the tableview.delegate and others? Make sure they are in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 1):

`delegate` property is not set on the `tableView`?
also `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` should be implemented

Answer (score 1):

you have to set your delegates and declare that you use those protocols

in file.m in didLoad

```
_table.delegate = self;
_table.dataSource = self;
```

in file.h when you declare the interface you have to add these protocols `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

Xcode will tell you which methods you must implement to respect the protocol.